# Algebra: How to solve for b when $\ln ab^t = -0.12t + 4.67$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm trying to solve the following for b:

$\ln ab^t = -0.12t + 4.67$ where $-0.12t + 4.67$ is the equation of a straight line.

I apply basic log rules:

$\ln a + t \ln b = -0.12t + 4.67$

According to the mark scheme / answer, you can just compare the coefficients of 't':

$-0.12 = \ln b$

But I don't understand, doesn't that imply the following:

$4.67 = \ln a$

If so, how can we be sure when there are two constants, `a` and `b`?

Comment: Yes, this means that both $a$ and $b$ have unique values when the above equation holds, although there is only one such equation. Is your question of the kind, why is it that two constants can be determined by one equation?

Answer (score 0):

using the logarithm rules we get
$$\ln(a)+t\ln(b)=-\frac{3}{25}t+\frac{467}{100}$$ and this is equivalent to
$$\ln(b)=\frac{1}{t}\left(-\frac{3}{25}t+\frac{467}{100}-\ln(a)\right)$$ thus
$$b=e^{\frac{1}{t}\left(-\frac{3}{25}t+\frac{467}{100}-\ln(a)\right)}$$

Comment: I think you should elaborate on the case where we don't want $b$ to be a function of $t$ so that your answer fits in with the marking scheme